# If day number is 12 or smaller, the macro takes the day instead of month

Tags: vba, database, date, format, excel-365

I created a macro that splits the date in month and year in two cells.

The date column:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIeFx.png)

The code:

```vb
sh1.Range("AB1") = "MM"
sh1.Range("AC1") = "YYYY"
sh1.Range("AD1") = "MM_mod"
sh1.Range("AE1") = "YYYY_mod"

Dim i As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long

startRow = Range("H1").Row

lastRow = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

num = lastRow - startRow + 1

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AB" & i) = Month(DateValue(Range("i" & i)))
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AC" & i) = Year(DateValue(Range("i" & i)))
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AD" & i) = Month(DateValue(Range("j" & i)))
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AE" & i) = Year(DateValue(Range("j" & i)))
Next i
```

On some colleagues' computers, if day number is 12 or smaller, the macro takes the day instead of month.

I thought the problem might be the format and I added `.NumberFormat` as follows:

```vb
sh1.Range("AB1") = "MM"
sh1.Range("AC1") = "YYYY"
sh1.Range("AD1") = "MM_mod"
sh1.Range("AE1") = "YYYY_mod"

Dim i As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long

startRow = Range("H1").Row

lastRow = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

num = lastRow - startRow + 1

For i = 2 To num
    Range("I" & i).NumberFormat = "d-m-yyyy h:mm"
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("J" & i).NumberFormat = "d-m-yyyy h:mm"
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AB" & i) = Month(DateValue(Range("i" & i)))
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AC" & i) = Year(DateValue(Range("i" & i)))
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AD" & i) = Month(DateValue(Range("j" & i)))
Next i

For i = 2 To num
    Range("AE" & i) = Year(DateValue(Range("j" & i)))
Next i
```

Comment: I don't know nothing about vba, but such kind of problems often arise from different language settings. Either on the computer or on the database.

Comment: Dates should always be threated as double so you don't run into these issues, use number format for display purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For i = 2 To num
        Range("AB" & i) = Month(Range("i" & i).Value2)
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To num
        Range("AC" & i) = Year(Range("i" & i).Value2)
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To num
        Range("AD" & i) = Month(Range("j" & i).Value2)
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To num
        Range("AE" & i) = Year(Range("j" & i).Value2)
    Next i
```

That should help against different settings